# Why didn't Luo Ji tell everyone what Ye Wenjie told him?

Tags: remembrance-of-earths-past, the-dark-forest

In *The Dark Forest*, while Luo Ji was trying to figure out the significance of what Ye Wenjie told him about cosmic sociology, why didn't he just publicly announce the few things she had said so the whole world could collectively figure it out?

He says that he knows his importance is because of what she told him, but still places himself under threat of assassination and the secret being lost to humanity forever by trying to figure it out and keeping it to himself.

Comment: Because he *doesn't know what he knows*